# ARCore: How to tell if the touch event falls on the AugmentedImage?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I need to know if the touch happened on the image that is recognized by ARCore, and if it is at, say, 25% Width and 50% Height of the image when measured from the top left edge of the image.